Writing Raster Bands using Raster IO
we have question regarding writing using gdals raster io using the C++ api:
        // Write the image data to the memory dataset
        for (int i = 0; i < channels; i++)
        {
            GDALRasterBand *band = memDataset->GetRasterBand(i + 1);
            gdalError = band->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, 0, cols, rows, mat.data + i, cols, rows, GDT_Byte, channels, 0);

            if (gdalError != CE_None)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Error writing data to memory dataset: " + std::string(CPLGetLastErrorMsg()));
            }
        }

What does it do?
I have a cv::Mat that i want to write using gdals writer but i came across an interesting problem that i cannot quite explain.
The problem
When i give as input a cv::Mat that has channels rgb, setting channels for nBandCount (in this case 3) band->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, 0, cols, rows, mat.data + i, cols, rows, GDT_Byte, **channels**, 0); the output looks correct. But in the case where i give is a cv::Mat that is simply a single channel, band->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, 0, cols, rows, mat.data + i, cols, rows, GDT_Byte, **channels**, 0); does not work, i need channel = 0 for it to output my tif/png/jpeg correct. Not sure why it behaves like this. Hopefully someone can englighten us on the fact why in the the case of a mono channel image we need nBandCount = 0 and for multichannel images we need nBandCount = number of channels?
